# Interface 'SessionHandlerInterface' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/CacheBasedSessionHandler.php on line8

Tags: php, laravel, docker, session, handler

I cloned a repository and created a development environment with docker and nginx as a server. However, when running the composer install command I run into the following error:

[Error running composer install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ow06.png)

And in the browser:

[in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N7EC.png)

I tried `pkg install php7.4-session` but im getting `zsh: command not found: pkg`

Using nginx so i can't setup php-fpm for apache2

What can be done?

I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Have you tried using `apt`? `sudo apt install php7.4-session`

Comment: Is already tryied @jrcamatog

Comment: Did it install? You can try restarting your PHP server after installation.

Comment: @jrcamatog i installed and restarted and didnt work unfortonately.

Comment: In fact, he didn’t even install it, he didn’t find the library